# How to avoid or UnitTest the accidental use of a concrete singleton type instead of its abstraction with StructureMap

Tags: c#, unit-testing, structuremap

I recently had the following bug in my code which took me for ever to debug. I wanted to inject an instance based on its interface like this:

```
MovementController(IMotorController motorController)
```

However I accidentally used the concrete type like this:

```
MovementController(MotorController motorController)
```

The project still built and ran fine until I tried to access the `motorController` from the `MovementController` instance. Since the underlying implementation of `IMotorController` accesses hardware, it has to be a singleton or my locks code. However, since I had other classes with the injected `IMotorController`, I now had two instances `MotorController` in my object-graph, which both accessed the hardware over a serial connection. This caused an error, at run time at a much lower level, which took me forever to debug and find the true cause.

How can I avoid this type of bug or write a unit test for my StructureMap registry to catch this subtle bug?

Comment: Let's see is I understand: You want a unit test to check that your controllers only have interfaces as constructor arguments? what kind of project is this? MVC, winform, wpf...?

Answer (score 1):

You could easily check for this using a static analysis tool like NDepend. With it you would just look for types that were controllers and then inspect their constructors and warn if you found any constructor parameters that were not interface types.

---

Just to refine the Steve answer, you could write a code rule that could look like: (with NDepend a code rule is a [C# LINQ query](http://www.ndepend.com/features/cqlinq#CQL) prefixed with `warnif count > 0`)

```
// <Name>Don't use MotorController, use IMotorController instead</Name>
warnif count > 0
from m in Application.Methods 
where m.IsUsing ("NamespaceA.MotorController ") &&
      m.ParentType.FullName != "NamespaceB.ClassThatCanUseMotorController "
select m
```

The rule can be refined easily if there are zero or many `ClassThatCanUseMotorController`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So the solution I came up with for my Unit Test, is to get all the instances that implement `IMotorController` and assert that their count equals `1`:

```
 var motorControllerInstances = container.GetAllInstances<IMotorController>().Select(x => x); // cast enumerable to List using Linq
 Assert.True(motorControllerInstances.Count == 1);
```

Not sure this is the most elegant way, but it seems to work.

**Update 1:**
This code does *not* catch the bug I had. I am still looking for a correct answer to my problem.

**Update 2:** I am getting closer. This will at least catch if you have accidentally *registered* a concrete type of the corresponding interface. However, it does not appear to check whether an instance of it was actually built.

```
    var allInterfaceInstances = dicFixture.result.Model.GetAllPossible<IMotorController>();
    Assert.True(allInterfaceInstance.Count() == 1);
```

Comment: This question is very interesting for me. I have a few questions to see if my solution can be applied to your situation. I am not familiar with structuremap but do you know if there is a way to identify all the mappings in the setup and the classes where you apply the interfaces?

Comment: @Nkosi Unfortunately I do not know if or how that is possible. However that would also be very interesting to me to validate my configuration. I will definitely look into that in the future. However I did find some SO post, where the poster mentioned, that the best way he found, was to make the field were the object reference is stored public and to verify that field directly. That does not seem pretty, but the poster did say he didn't find a better way. Unfortunately I don't have the link anymore and don't know which StructureMap version he talked about.

Comment: Ok. well for an ASP.Net MVC project I was using DI and wanted to make sure all my controllers were being injected with only interfaces or abstract classes. No concrete implementations. So I wrote a unit test that check all controllers (MVC and WEB API) to make sure that their constructors had no classes being injected into the controllers, only abstractions. So I was able to identify those classes by their `IController` and `ApiController` inheritance respectively and then check their constructors. From your example I was not able to tell what type of project you had.

Comment: Well in my case it is a WPF application. But the test you wrote sounds very interesting. Would it be possible for you to share the code or describe how you accomplished this? BTW: There seems to be a bug in my solution above, so I am still looking for a good solution.

Comment: @packoman, this solution looks good. What exactly is wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

The safest solution is to check during runtime that only one instance of `MotorController` is created. For instance you could count the number of instances of `MotorController` with a static counter variable:

```
public class MotorController : IMotorController
{
    private static bool instantiated;

    public MotorController(...)
    {
        if (instantiated)
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                "MotorController can only be instantiated once.")

        ...

        instantiated = true;
    }

    ...
}
```

I'd usually consider this bad design, because whether a class is used as a singleton or not is something only the dependency injection framework should care about. Also note that this is not thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

In trying to adhere to the **D** in **SOLID**

> Dependency inversion principle where
>       one should “Depend upon Abstractions. Do not depend upon concretions

for a project. In this case Asp.Net-MVC5, I wanted a way to make sure that all controllers (MVC and WebAPI2) were following this pattern where they were not dependent on concretions.

The original idea came from an article I had read where a unit test was created to scan all controllers to make sure that they had explicit authorization defined. I applied a similar thinking in checking that all controllers had constructors that depended on abstractions.

```
[TestClass]
public class ControllerDependencyTests : ControllerUnitTests {
    [TestMethod]
    public void All_Controllers_Should_Depend_Upon_Abstractions() {

        var controllers = UnitTestHelper.GetAssemblySources() //note this is custom code to get the assemblies to reflect.
            .SelectMany(assembly => assembly.GetTypes())
            .Where(t => typeof(IController).IsAssignableFrom(t) || typeof(System.Web.Http.Controllers.IHttpController).IsAssignableFrom(t));

        var constructors = controllers
            .SelectMany(type => type.GetConstructors())
            .Where(constructor => {

                var parameters = constructor.GetParameters();
                var result = constructor.IsPublic
                    && parameters.Length > 0
                    && parameters.Any(arg => arg.ParameterType.IsClass && !arg.ParameterType.IsAbstract);

                return result;
            });
        // produce a test failure error mssage if any controllers are uncovered
        if (constructors.Any()) {
            var errorStrings = constructors
                .Select(c => {
                    var parameters = string.Join(", ", c.GetParameters().Select(p => string.Format("{0} {1}", p.ParameterType.Name, p.Name)));
                    var ctor = string.Format("{0}({1})", c.DeclaringType.Name, parameters);
                    return ctor;
                }).Distinct();

            Assert.Fail(String.Format("\nType depends on concretion instead of its abstraction.\n{0} Found :\n{1}",
                            errorStrings.Count(),
                            String.Join(Environment.NewLine, errorStrings)));
        }
    }
}
```

So given the following example. (Note I adapted this to MVC)

```
public class MovementController : Controller {
    public MovementController(MotorController motorController) {
        //...
    }
}

public interface IMotorController {
    //...
}

public class MotorController : IMotorController {
    //...
}
```

the unit test would fail with ...

```
Result Message: Assert.Fail failed. 
Type depends on concretion instead of its abstraction.
1 Found :
MovementController(MotorController motorController)
```

This worked for me because I had a common type to look for with the `IController` and `ApiController`.

There is room for improvement on the test but is should be a good starting point for you.